# Dynamic routerLink value from ngFor item giving error "Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected"

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to set the `routerLink` value in a directive based on a dynamic set of items from the component. But an error is being thrown from Angular2:

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 1 in [ {{item.routerLink}} ] in AppHeader@5:40 ("
    <a *ngFor="let item of headerItems" [ERROR ->][routerLink]=" {{item.routerLink}} ">
      {{item.text}}
    </a>
"): Header@5:40
```

**header.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router-deprecated';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './app/components/header/header.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppHeader {
  headerItems: Object[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.headerItems.push(
      { classes: 'navLink', routerLink: ['/Home'], text: 'Home' }
    );
  }
}
```

**header.component.html**

```
<div id="HeaderRegion">
  <nav class="nav">
    <a *ngFor="let item of headerItems" [routerLink]=" {{item.routerLink}} ">
      {{item.text}}
    </a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: just had the issue, if solutions above give Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. and if your template is inside a custom module (like I did), dont forget to import RouterModule in your module too :-P

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can't use `[]` combined with `{{}}` either the former or the later

```
[routerLink]="item.routerLink"
```

Should do what you want.

```
routerLink="{{item.routerLink}}"
```

would bind `item.routerLink.toString()` to the `routerLink` property.

Comment: To get this to work I had to change headerItems to " routerLink: '/Home' " and add the brackets [ ] in the ngFor loop, link this [routerLink]: "[item.routerLink]"

Comment: The brackets around the path shouldn't be necessary. Are you using the newest version of Angular2 and the router?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. RouterLink supports both, an array of router commands, or a path as string.

Comment: it's worked for me  when to us `routerLink="{{item.name}}"`

Comment: In case you are appending for input string prop `routerLink="/someurl/{{callMethodTogetDinamicString(someprop.prop1)}}"`

Answer (score 17):

You may also go with the following code to pass expression with some text.

```
<div *ngFor="let customer of customers">
   <a [routerLink]="'customer/'+customer.index">Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could have found the answer by this time, for me removing {{}} resolved the similar issue. Your code could be

```
<a *ngFor="let item of headerItems" [routerLink]="item.routerLink">
  {{item.text}}
</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this worked for us:

```
<input type="checkbox" [id]="['btn.botStepState-'+i]" [(ngModel)]="btn.botStepState" name="btn.botStepState-{{i}}" (change)="changeHandler($event)" class="cbx hidden" />
```

- **Property binding** i.e. `[]` required `[]` to evaluate values
- **Model binding** i.e. `[()]` required nothing special
- **Interpolation** i.e. `{{}}` could be used with general attributes
- **Event binding** i.e. `()` worked great with functions

Comment: I fail to se how this is helpful, nothing in here is is related to the question outside of what a property binding is.

Comment: @dudewad in my example, I'm showing how to use the synatx in general which applies to the question as well - so that the asker can take help from it.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to create router link by getting dynamic value from ngFor , you can do using below example

```
<div *ngFor = "let item of items"> 
<a [routerLink] = "['./item-details/' + item.id]">{{item.name}}</a></div>
```

that is , simply append the value you receive to the url you want to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example of how to make your routes dynamic

**in your html component**

```
<ul class="nav side-menu">
                <li *ngFor="let data of dataPermiso;let i= index">
                  <a><i class="{{data.icono}}"></i> {{data.categoria}} <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                  <ul class="nav child_menu">
                    <li *ngFor="let item of data.permisoList;let a = index">
                      <a [routerLink]="item.ruta">{{item.titulo}}</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
</ul>
```

**in your component ts**

```
  public dataPermiso:any[] = [];

  constructor(private loginserv: LoginService) {
    this.loadPermiso();
  }



  ngOnInit() {

  }

  public loadPermiso(){
    this.loginserv.listPermisos(this.dataStorage.idrol).subscribe((data)=>{
      this.dataPermiso= data;
    });
  }
```