# Dynamic RouterLink href value is changing but router-link is correct

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an ng-for loop outputting my menu class dynamically. The first time the page is loaded, the ng-reflect-router-link and ng-reflect-href are set correctly. The issue is after on of the links are clicked, all ng-reflect-hrefs change to whatever link was clicked.

**routes.ts**

```
import { RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { Home } from './views/home/home';
import { FetchData } from './components/fetch-data/fetch-data';
import { Counter } from './components/counter/counter';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [

    { path: 'home', component: Home },
    { path: 'counter', component: Counter },
    { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchData }
];
```

**sidebar-menu.ts**

```
import * as ng from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Http} from './index.ts'

@ng.Component({
    selector: 'sidebar-menu',
    template: require('./sidebar-menu.html'),
    directives: [...ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class SidebarMenu {
    public menus: Menu[];
    constructor(http: Http) {
        //todo - put this in a service.ts
        http.get('/api/Menu/Menus').subscribe(result => {
            this.menus = result.json();
        });
    }


}
```

**menu.ts**

```
interface Menu {
    name: string;
    decorator: string;
}
```

**sidebar-menu.html**

```
<ul>    
<li *ngFor="#menu of menus" >
<a [routerLink]="menu.name">
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-th-list {{menu.decorator}}'></span> {{menu.name}}</a>
/li>
</ul>
```

After I click a link (couter is the link I clicked in the example below), this is what the html looks like:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-sidebar">

        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object]"
}--><li>
            <a ng-reflect-router-link="counter" ng-reflect-href="/counter" href="/counter">
                <span ng-reflect-class-name="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list " class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list " classname="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list "></span> counter
            </a>
        </li><li>
            <a ng-reflect-router-link="fetch-data" ng-reflect-href="/counter" href="/counter">
                <span ng-reflect-class-name="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list " class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list " classname="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list "></span> fetch-data
            </a>
        </li>
        </ul>
```

My project is set up very similar to [Dynamic routerLink value from ngFor item giving error "Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078494/dynamic-routerlink-value-from-ngfor-item-giving-error-got-interpolation).
but my links are displaying correctly, unlike that post.

Comment: links are looking correct doesn't mean that it's correct, what your console says about it?

Comment: no errors in console. when I log this.menu, it looks as it should.

Comment: what is name in menu? can you share that piece of code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was my json object had more properties defined than my javascript interface.

[image: Menu object]