# Validating *ngFor used forms using angular 2 [formControl]

Tags: javascript, html, validation, angular, typescript

I have an angular Form and it used `*ngFor` for repeat an input box. Also, I have to validate dynamically all input boxes that are generated by `*ngFor`.

There is a JSON array called list that contains Questions. and I have to generate input boxes for answers and they should be validated. Validation information also in the list.

This is an example of the list

```
[{id:1,
mandatory:false,
questionDescription:"Blue flags are in position and contain words “Stop, Tank Car Connected” or “Stop, Men at Work”",
questionType:1,
validation:{maximum:100,minimum:0}},
{id:2,
mandatory:true,
questionDescription:"Wheels are chocked and handbrake(s) set” or “Stop, Men at Work",
questionType:2,
validation:{maxLength:10,minLength:3}}]
```

I tried to validate generated input boxes as described in here.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-form-validation (see validation forms there).

So I have to give validation information for each input boxes like below.
(this example from given tutorial)

```
constructor(fb: FormBuilder){
    this.complexForm = fb.group({
      'firstName' : [null, Validators.required],
      'lastName': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(10)])]
    })
```

this is the HTML for it.

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text"[formControl]="complexForm.controls['firstName']">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" >
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['lastName']">
      </div>
```

So in my case, all input boxes generate by `*ngFor` and I have to assign tags like `firstName`, `lastName` dynamically to those boxes.
So I used `question.id` as that tag and implemented control group as followed.

```
inspectionForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.questionTemplate = templateService.getQuestionTemplate();

    let objString: string = "{";

    for (let item of this.questionTemplate.sectionList[0].questionList) {
      if (item.questionType == 2) {
        objString += '"' + item.id + '":null,';
      }
    }

    objString = objString.slice(0, -1);
    objString += '}';
    let objJson = JSON.parse(objString);

    for (let item of this.questionTemplate.sectionList[0].questionList) {
      if (item.questionType == 2) {
        objJson[item.id] = [null,Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(item.validation.minLength), Validators.maxLength(item.validation.maxLength)])];
      }
    }
    this.inspectionForm = fb.group(objJson);
}
```

and here is my HTML code.

```
    <form [formGroup]="inspectionForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(inspectionForm.value)">

            <div *ngFor="let question of section.questionList" [ngSwitch]="question.questionType">
              <ion-row *ngSwitchCase="QuestionType.String">
                <ion-col width-80>{{question.questionDescription}}</ion-col>
                <ion-col width-20>
                  <ion-input id="{{question.id}}" type="text" class="inspection-bottom-border" [formControl]="inspectionForm.controls['{{question.id}}']"></ion-input>
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!inspectionForm.valid">Submit</button>
            </div>

   </form>
```

**The Problem is....**

If I define `[formControl]` as `[formControl]="inspectionForm.controls['{{question.id}}']"`

I get an error like follows,

```
unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 25 in [inspectionForm.controls['{{question.id}}']] in InspectionPage@36:91 ("idth-20>
              <ion-input id="{{question.id}}" type="text" class="inspection-bottom-border" [ERROR ->][formControl]="inspectionForm.controls['{{question.id}}']"></ion-input>
```

then I searched for an answer in StackOverflow, I found someone has said don't use `[]` and `{{}}` in one time ([Dynamic routerLink value from ngFor item giving error "Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078494/dynamic-routerlink-value-from-ngfor-item-giving-error-got-interpolation))

But if I removed `[]` and defined as follows

```
formControl="inspectionForm.controls['{{question.id}}']"
```

I get an error as follows

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./InspectionPage class InspectionPage - inline template:36:91 caused by: Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'inspectionForm.controls['2']'
```

(this '2' the is question.id of first type 2 question)

if I define as follows same error occurs

```
formControl="inspectionForm.controls['2']"
```

But the problem is if I define as follows with `[formControl]`

```
[formControl]="inspectionForm.controls['2']"
```

**The app is Working Perfectly....**

But I have to give `question.id` dynamically. How I can do that?

Are there someone have a solution for this error. Please give a suggestion.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try `[formControl]="inspectionForm.controls[question.id]"`?

Comment: Thank you very much.... Now it works.... You saved me... thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `[formControl]="inspectionForm.controls[question.id]"`

*Thanks @Sasxa for the answer*

Comment: Unfortunately, `form.controls['']` is not supported by AoT.

Comment: it's better to use `[formControl]="inspectionForm.get(question.id)"`