# Have navigation links in table for each row

Tags: angular-mdl

I am trying to figure out if its possible to register links in the Table component of angular2-mdl.

Idea is that one column will contain the anchor to the component user needs to go to.

Normally this would be easy on html as you use [routerLink]="" on anchor or button, but is it possible to generate this in the TS file and pass it to the table element?

Answer (score 0):

remove the [] from the routerLink element and insert your variable.

like:
[Dynamic routerLink value from ngFor item giving error "Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078494/dynamic-routerlink-value-from-ngfor-item-giving-error-got-interpolation)

Comment: Can you give example how you would do this in the TS (not html) and have it register on html?